# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Functions.telemetry' PocSendGrid

Tags: c#

I have the following error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Functions.telemetry'
```

IN the following code:

```
 private TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called sendgridqueue.
        public static async Task ProcessQueueMessageAsync([QueueTrigger("sendgridqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            Message msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(message);
            await Execute(msg, log);           
        }


        static async Task Execute(Message message, TextWriter log)
        {
            telemetry.TrackEvent("WinGame");


            log.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: Message is being sent with subject {1}, to {2}, and body{3}", DateTime.Now, message.Subject, message.To.ToString(), message.HtmlBody));
            var client = new SendGridClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sendgridapikey"]);
            var from = new EmailAddress(message.From);
            var subject = message.Subject;
            var to = new EmailAddress(message.To.ToString());
            var plainTextContent = message.PlainTextBody;
            var htmlContent = message.HtmlBody;
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            log.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: Message was sent with subject {1}, to {2}, and body{3}", DateTime.Now, message.Subject, message.To.ToString(), message.HtmlBody));

            log.WriteLine(String.Format("Message took: {0} between queueing and sending", (DateTime.Now - message.DateandTimeSent).TotalMilliseconds));

        }
```

However if I remove the static keyword, then I get another error, I dont want to instantiate the TelemetryClient every time.

Comment: `However if I remove the static keyword, then I get another error` - I can expand my answer if you explain what this error is

Comment: I get the same error but in the await line

Comment: You need to take static off *both* methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`telemetry` is an *instance* variable - a new one is created every time you instantiate this class.

Your methods are *static* - they cannot access *instance* variables.

An easy solution is just instantiate `TelemetryClient` inside your `Execute` method:

```
static async Task Execute(Message message, TextWriter log)
{
    TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
    telemetry.TrackEvent("WinGame");
    ...
```